# Python 3 Discord Bot Function Add To Itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hello I'm trying to make a command for discord bot so that when I type .count it will show +1 but then if I type it again it will show +2 and if I type it again it will show +3 etc. if anyone knows what to do let me know thanks I've tried so many things including

```
COUNT = 0
def increment():
    global COUNT
    COUNT += 1
increment()

print(COUNT)
```

and that didn't work just stays 1

UPDATE: JUST TRIED

```
if "!counter" == message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send
        def get_var_value(filename="store.dat"):
            with open(filename, "a+") as f:
                f.seek(0)
                val = int(f.read() or 0) + 1
                f.seek(0)
                f.truncate()
                f.write(str(val))
                return val
                your_counter = get_var_value()
                print("This script has been run {} times.".format(your_counter))
```

and well that did kinda work by itself I cannot make it say it in chat "Type Error: object method can't be used in 'await' expression" as well it wouldn't change depending on who ever the user who did the command was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in your
`await message.channel.send`
Right now you are awaiting the function itself, but you have to pass it an argument, like this:

```py
await message.channel.send(counter)
```

Now your approach with writing a file seems a pretty solid idea, but we can simplify the process:

```py
if "!counter" == message.content.lower():
    # a try except statement so that we only read the file if it exists and has the correct value
    try: 
        with open("store.dat", "r") as f:
            counter = int(f.read()) # read in the file contents
    except (FileNotFoundError, ValueError):
        counter = 0 # if something goes wrong, we reset the counter

    counter += 1
    await message.channel.send(f"This command has been called {counter} times") # give feedback in the channel
    with open("store.dat", "w") as f:
        f.write(str(counter)) # write the contents back into the file
```

Comment: Thank you very much I just have a side question why does it matter how far code is spaced in because when I pasted in what you sent me it didn't work but when I moved it around and lined it up it worked and also how would you make it so it's a different counter per user

Comment: Those are a lot of different questions with quite complex answers.
Here are the short versions: 1. Yes it does matter how far code is spaced. Python works with linebreaks and tabs instead of curly brackets. 2. You need to have a seperate file for every single user, but at this point I reccomend using a database like SQLlite.